# How to find when a user last changed their password using Windows registry

Tags: windows, windows-7, registrykey

I've been given some images of a hard drive, and I have to find out when the user last changed their password. I've found from other keys in the registry that it's a Windows 7 machine, but I don't know how to find when they last changed their password.

I found a registry key for MaximumPasswordAge, which on this machine is set to 30, and the DisablePasswordChange key is set to 0. How can I use this to figure out the date when the user last set their password?

Comment: I also need to 'find last password change date and time" in windows XP , using Registry key .